# Blender not saving changes to object's origin point

Tags: objects, transforms

On my current .blend file, when I edit a particular object's origin point and save it, opening the file again resets the origin back to where it was before. I'm unable to save the object with a new origin location. I tried doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to set to apply location, rotation, and scale, and then saving it, but upon reopening the object was scaled strangely and the origin once again not in the right location.

Comment: [Ctrl]+[A] > *apply location* will move the origin to the world's origin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you accidentally added a keyframe to your object. So even if you move it, it will snap back to the keyframe position. You can fix this by opening the *NLA editor* and deleting all animation on your cube, or opening the *Dope Sheet* and deleting the keyframe you don't want. A common way to add keyframes by accident is by pressing the *Auto Keyframe* button (at  the bottom of the timeline), this causes any rotation, scale, or movement to your object to be keyframed.
[image]

You can acsess the *Dope Sheet* through this menu:
[image]

Once in the *Dope Sheet*, select the keyframes you don't want and press delete.
[image]

Comment: I would upvote 10 times if that was possible .. Thanks!